# Is it safe to use pdf2swf.exe in C# web application ? (through System.Diagnostics.Process)

Tags: c#, pdf, flash, code-behind

I have a question about converting pdf to swf in real time in c# code behind, so that i can use FlexPaper to display the pdf document. I have tried to find any solution to generate the swf, but unluckily, I only got a method which use "pdf2swf.exe" by calling "System.Diagnostics.Process" and just like a call in command prompt in the code behind.

So, is this a proper approach? In order to let code behind to see the exe file, I have to place the exe file within the Web Dir branch, and this file may go to the public.

Can anyone can give me an advice on how to convert pdf to swf in proper way?

thanks

jack

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the process that converts the pdf and shows the created swf.

Let a service of some sorts pick up pdf files in a special directory and convert them to a special directory. This way the asp.net process does not have to be able to start processes and write data. It just has to place the file in the correct folder.

Calling external processes can create dangerous situations if you don't handle error codes correctly. Do you catch convertion erros in any way?

Comment: yes ... i will catch any error during conversion... so i have to make a schedule job to check the folder which start conversion if pdf exist. the page need to keep monitor the folder if swf file exit, it show on the flexpaper? uh... let me think about that .. thank~

Comment: I'd go for a windows service with a file system watcher.